# Accessing model through other model via django queryset

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-queryset

I need to access columns in particular table through foreign keys in another table. I wrote it in SQL, but how it will be in queryset language?

This is models.py

```py
class carModel(models.Model):
    id_car_model = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    id_car_mark = models.ForeignKey(carMark,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_create = models.IntegerField(max_length=10,null=True)
    date_update = models.IntegerField(max_length=10,null=True)
    id_car_type = models.ForeignKey(carType,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name_rus = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)

class CarParts(models.Model):
    id_catalog = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
    vendor_code = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    subgroup = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
    side = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
    trade_mark = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
    original_number = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
    request = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    sum = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    availability = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)

class interimTable(models.Model):
    id_interim = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    id_catalog=models.ForeignKey(CarParts, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_car_model = models.ForeignKey(carModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is SQL request, that is successful. I need same thing, but like querySet, to use it in further code.

```
Select title,side,price
from carinfo_carparts,carinfo_interimtable,carinfo_carmodel 
where id_catalog = carinfo_interimtable.id_catalog_id
and  carinfo_carmodel.id_car_model = carinfo_interimtable.id_car_model_id
and carinfo_carmodel.name='Civic';
```

[this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhs8y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
CarParts.objects.filter(interimtable__id_car_model__name='Civic').values('title', 'side', 'price')
```